# Weekly once scheduler job in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am new to `C#`.
As to my present task. I suppose to execute a set logic once a week (i.e Every Sunday).
How to do this `C#` . i known this can be done in php by "**Cron job**".

Comment: As you're a new user to this site I recommend you to go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: cron job is something done by the operating system, not by php or c#

Comment: @peterpeterson: I dare to object. There are valid use cases for an application to run regularly, e.g. updating it's database from an external source, maintenance and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following options

1. You create a windows service that takes an input from string . then parse the string and do the task using a timer.
2. Use the quart.net service and proceed.
3. Make use of windows task scheduler services.

For Quartz.Net, you can refer to the cron trigger

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger